# Appending a dictionary containing a list to another dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I've got the following dictionary, as you can see the list of bids made is an item in the dictionary at the same level as the actual job.

What I'd like to be able to do is append the bids:[] key pair to the job:{} dictionary so that I can then allow a user to give a job ID to the program and it will output a list of applicant names.

Here's what the dictionary looks like, and unfortunately I don't have any control over how it's created initially.

```
{u'bids': [{u'applicantId': 221,
            u'Name': u'name name',
            u'bidID': 2},
           {u'applicantId': 356,
            u'Name': u'name name',
            u'bidID': 5},
           {u'applicantId': 240,
            u'Name': u'name name',
            u'bidID': 9}],
 u'job': {u'address': u'6 something St',
          u'bids': None,
          u'budget': 30.0,
          u'jobID': 10}}
```

So I'd like a user to give me the JobID and it will output a list of the names of the people who applied.

Any help here?

Comment: What you've tried so far? and what's `bids:[] key pair`?

Comment: Why don't you just do `d['job']['bids'] = d['bids']`?

Comment: @Kasramvd sorry I just meant the bids:[] item. I was trying this:
`response = {the dictionary above}`
`job = response['job']`
`bids = response['bids']`
`new = job.update(bids)`

Comment: @TimFuchs can you explain that a bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this, if `d` is your original dictionary:

```
jobs[d['job']['jobID']] = d['job']
jobs[d['job']['jobID']]['bids'] = d['bids']
```

Now you can search for all applicants for a job with a given `JobID`:

```
applicants = [bid['Name'] for bid in jobs[JobID]['bids']]
```

Comment: In this case, are you creating a new list called "jobs" here?

Comment: I am actually supposing that a dictionary `jobs` with JobID's as keys already exists, and I am just adding another JobID to it.

Comment: I've understood it, by taking your code and applying to my data I'm able to make it work! I needed to add another loop since the data above arrives in an array since there's more than one job posted. This worked perfectly